Simplify an expression that makes nested calls to coalesce
I am new to Terraform and looking at a code like this one wondering if it could be simplified:
  compartment_id = length(coalesce(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment, [])) > 0 ? (
     length(coalesce(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments, [])) > 0 ? (
       data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments[0].id) : null) : null

Is there a way to write this expression more elegantly?

You can use the try function to make the expression significantly more concise (note documentation also states the function is intended for your use case).
compartment_id = try(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments[0].id, null)


The nested length and coalesce functions can be replaced with a more straightforward approach using lookup or just conditional logic. Here’s a simplified version:
compartment_id = (
  data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments[0].id if 
  length(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment) > 0 && 
  length(data.oci_identity_compartments.compartment[0].compartments) > 0 
  else null
)


I don't think this is the correct HCL syntax.

The HCL syntax is wrong. Instead of x if (cond) else y the correct syntax is (cond) ? x : y (ternary operator)
